# Connecting MATLAB to Firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, matlab, firebase

I want to ask if there is any way to connect Firebase database with MATLAB, I'm plotting ECG signals in MATLAB and I want to send these signals to the database.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native Firebase SDK for Matlab, nor a native Matlab SDK for Firebase.

But many Firebase products have a REST API, which allows you to access them from any technology that can makes HTTP calls.

For example, have a look at the REST API documentation for [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api), and the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).