# Sending data to Firebase from Matlab

Tags: matlab, rest, firebase

I want to save data to firebase from Matlab. Does firebase have similar api calls like ThingSpeak? How can i send JSON data from matlab by making API calls?

I am making API calls from Matlab like for JSON:

```
    Firebase_Url = 'https://ecgproject-86945.firebaseio.com/';
    writeApiKey = '***';
    data = ['api_key=',writeApiKey,'&name=',"JSOpn9ZC54A4P4RoqVa"];
    response = webwrite(Firebase_Url,data) 

    %data = struct('api_key',writeApiKey,'field1',data); //also tries this
    %options = weboptions('MediaType','application/json');
```

The Error:

```
Error using readContentFromWebService (line 46)
The server returned the status 405 with message "Method Not Allowed" in response to the
request to URL https://ecgproject-86945.firebaseio.com/.

Error in webwrite (line 139)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = readContentFromWebService(connection, options);

Error in Untitled (line 16)
response = webwrite(Firebase_Url,data)
```

Comment: I answered a very similar question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467712/connecting-matlab-to-firebase-database

Comment: Yes but doesnt specify how to use the Rest service from Matlab.

Comment: I did a quick search on "performing HTTP calls from Matlab" and saw a lot of promising results. Did you try any of those yet? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I used Thingspeak Previously. I follwed the tutorial as for webwrite() of matlab. But i guess firebase has different formatting for the data.Here is the link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html . I have also updated my question with the code i am running on matlab now for firebase.

Comment: If you tried something, edit your question to include what you tried (which you just did I see). From the error message it looks like you're not passing a request body, which is required when performing a HTTP POST request. Did you try the "Write JSON Object" example from https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [mathworks documentation on `webwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html) you need to use the two-parameter version of the method, passing in the additional information inside the second, `data` object:

```
data = ['api_key=',writeApiKey,'&name=',"JSOpn9ZC54A4P4RoqVa"];

response = webwrite(FirebaseURL,data)
```

Comment: This also doesn't work. I have edited my question also for this method. I think the firebase API has different formatting. Have you worked with firebase api from matlab? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution apparently i didn't add .json at the end of the URL. Thank You. Here is the solution:

```
Firebase_Url = 'https://***.firebaseio.com/Channel1.json';
response = webwrite(Firebase_Url,'{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }')
```